# How to install ruby 1.9.2 on debian lenny?

Tags: ruby, debian

I would like to install the newest ruby and rails on my debian lenny server.

I found the package http://packages.debian.org/lenny-backports/ruby1.9.1-full but when I try to install it with I just get:

```
atlas:~# apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package ruby1.9.1-full
```

My sources.list looks like this:

```
atlas:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian/ lenny main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian/ lenny main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib non-free
deb-src http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib non-free
```

What do I have to do to get it installed?

Comment: [superuser](http://superuser.com/) might be the better place to ask.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: I agree. This has nothing to do with programming. It's basically "how do I use my operating system", which is a [SuperUser](http://SuperUser.Com/) type question, although it is probably even more suited to the [Unix & Linux StackExchange](http://Unix.StackExchange.Com/), but there is currently no way to migrate questions there.

Comment: Hm, ok, never heard of superuser untill now, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @jorg unix.SE has launched recently; can u check again?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Stop.  Go back.  Install whatever version of Ruby Debian has, probably 1.8.7 or 1.8.7.  Then install RVM.  I have some directions for [using RVM with Ubuntu](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/ss/installrvmlinux.htm) (sorry, not Debian, but it's close).  Seriously, RVM makes installing any version of Ruby easy.  Then, use RVM to install Ruby 1.9.2, you don't want 1.9.1.

This will work depending on what you want to use Ruby for.  For development purposes, using RVM works really well.  For server purposes, I suppose it can be used, but you might have some problems.  I think RVM gives you some scripts you can use to run Ruby scripts with init scripts and cron jobs.

Or, you can just install from source.  It's not hard, and it's not the debian way, but it'll get the job done.  This may be preferable to installing some third party packages, where you may have no idea what they did during compile time, and how to get speedy updates in the case of a security vulnerability.  Using RVM or installing manually from source, you can update whenever it's needed.

Comment: I tried it from source for 2 days now. Ruby is not the problem but then I always get problems with rubygems or something, when I finally got gem working and installing stuff when I want to run a script it always says: "gem_prelude.rb:114:in `push_gem_version_on_load_path': undefined method `<=>' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"

Comment: That's strange...  I've installed Ruby many times from source (and now use RVM exclusively, I really can't recommend it any harder), and I've never encountered anything like that.  But first, were you trying to install 1.9.1?  Because 1.9.1 never really was widely supported (it was kind of an experimental branch), if you want a Ruby 1.9.x, you should be using Ruby 1.9.2.  Also note that Ruby 1.9.2 comes with Rubygems already installed, so if you try to install that, you'll just run into more problems.  You should just need to install Ruby 1.9.2, and then sudo gem install rails.  That's it.

Comment: I think the problem is that if I install it from source, I don't know where it is installed to and therefore do not use the right gem command or something. After two days of trying there are some more versions of the same names all over the place ;)

Comment: I need this for my server, and I want to use passenger and its apache-module together with the 1.9.2 and rails 3, will this be possible? I was reading about rvm on their website and they say everywhere that it is per console.

Comment: Install rvm first, then the ruby you prefer (I suggest ree on a server unless you use specific 1.9.2 features). After install passenger gem trigger the easy wizards it provides (you can choose between apache or nginx module).

Comment: I feel like I should point this out for future readers - the ruby1.9.1 package in Debian actually contains Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 8):

First run this:

```
apt-get update
```

Then install Ruby

```
apt-get install ruby
```

Then you need rubygems

```
wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/60718/rubygems-1.3.5.tgz
```

Untar rubygems...

```
tar xvf rubygems-1.3.5.tgz
cd rubygems-1.3.5
ruby setup.rb
ln -s /usr/bin/gem1.8 /usr/bin/gem
```

Now update rubygems

```
gem update --system
```

And now we can install rails

```
gem install rails
```

You can check if the install was succesfull with the following commands:

```
ruby -v
rails -v
gem -v
```

If you need more help let me know!

If you want Ruby 1.9.2 replace the following commands:

```
apt-get install ruby
```

with

```
apt-get install ruby1.9
```

If you need the dev headers you can just install ruby1.9-dev.

```
apt-get install ruby1.9-dev
```

If you cant install them this way you need to look at your apt-get sources.

```
apt-cache search ruby1.9

libhtree-ruby1.9 - HTML/XML tree library for Ruby 1.9
....
libinotify-ruby1.9 - Ruby interface to Linux's inotify system
....
libdbm-ruby1.9 - DBM interface for Ruby 1.9
libgdbm-ruby1.9 - GDBM interface for Ruby 1.9
....
**ruby1.9-dev** - Header files for compiling extension modules for the Ruby 1.9
ruby1.9-elisp - ruby-mode for Emacsen
ruby1.9-examples - Examples for Ruby 1.9
**ruby1.9** - Interpreter of object-oriented scripting language Ruby 1.9
libstfl-ruby1.9 - Ruby bindings for the structured terminal forms language/library
```

I hope this helps.And i would suggest using RVM (but i didn't cover that here..)

Comment: this would install ruby 1.8, I need ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 4):

RVM is a great solution, but *not for production environments*. Its $PATH magic is too finicky and breaks too often.

I'd suggest building a .deb for yourself. You compile Ruby from source, and then install it using checkinstall. Then you can distribute the .deb it creates to any machine, and install/uninstall it using dpkg *like you would with any package*.

[Here's a tutorial](http://threebrothers.org/brendan/blog/ruby-1-9-2-on-ubuntu-11-04/) that does this in Ubuntu; it should translate very easily to Debian.

Answer (score 3):

Don't install any rubies by Debian, recently one of the main maintainer gives up on them: http://www.lucas-nussbaum.net/blog/?p=617
Debian's rubies used to be ugly and often broken, so the best way to install it is by now using rvm, a little program that manages gemset and different versions of rubies in the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install a package from the Lenny backports repository, you obviously need to have it in your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://Backports.Debian.Org/debian-backports lenny-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://Backports.Debian.Org/debian-backports lenny-backports main contrib non-free
```

Since the backports are not subject to the normal strict quality review that other packages are, they are disabled by default. If you want to install a package from the backports repository, you have to explicitly pass the distribution to `apt-get` or `aptitude`, just like with the `experimental` repository:

```
apt-get -t lenny-backports install ruby191-full # or
aptitude -t lenny-backports install ruby191-full
```

Since the backported packages are disabled by default, you won't even get security updates for them, unless you add a pinning in `/etc/apt/preferences`:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=lenny-backports
Pin-Priority: 200
```

[All of this is clearly spelled out on the Debian Backports website.](http://Backports.Debian.Org/Instructions/)

Note that you should be careful not to mix package management systems. You should *either* install all Ruby libraries via APT *or* via RubyGems, but it's generally not a good idea to mix them.

Also, if you use Debian's RubyGems package, you should only update it via APT, not via RubyGems's builtin update mechanism (`gem update --system`). Actually, I believe that in current versions, Debian has removed the update mechanism to prevent this, but it wasn't always the case.

Personally, I use the Debian Ruby packages without problems on a production server, and I don't use RubyGems *at all*, I only use the Ruby libraries provided by Debian.

Answer (score 2):

was just going to add a comment to the original question, but I guess I haven't earned that priviledge yet...

Anyways, I found this helpful link and thought I would share it:

http://blog.binarybalance.com.au/2010/08/28/compiling-ruby-1-9-2-on-debian-lenny